# Font measurements visualizer

Tags: linux, data-visualization, font-utility, font

There are a few utilities for showcasing fonts/font families from a file in a Window. Windows has something like this (I forget the name); and on Linux you have gnome-font-view and perhaps something in KDE as well.

However - those don't let you see various metrics/dimensional features of fonts: The Em square, ascender and descender lengths, x-height vs M-height etc. You also typically can't compare sizes and measures against some other font as the baseline, or even a 1x1 box of some unit (cm, in, etc.).

Is there some utility which offers this functionality? If not, perhaps even a full-fledged font editor, or non-font application, which offers this?

Required features:

- Runs on Linux
- Runs on x86_64
- Supports TTF and OTF

Desired features:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Multi-platform
- Supports more font file formats

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest taking a look at [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/).

- Cross Platform including Linux
- Free & Open Source (contribution requested)
- 32 bit x86 but runs on 64
- Supports TTF, OTF and many others

It offers a metrics window amongst many other features.
[image: FontForge]

Comment: Needless to say it is scriptable in ___python___!